# Apache DirectoryMatch apply in one subfolder but not in another

Tags: regex, apache

i'm trying to apply some rules for a subfolder but not for another subfolder.

I have this

```
SetEnvIf Referer "((.+\.)?domain\.com|localhost)" localreferer
<DirectoryMatch "/bin(.+/)?">
   Require env localreferer
</DirectoryMatch>
```

And it is working fine. But now I need that this rule does not apply to /bin/public. I will have /bin/private and /bin/public, i need to apply the rule for /bin/private

I tried with

```
SetEnvIf Referer "((.+\.)?domain\.com|localhost)" localreferer
 <DirectoryMatch "/bin/private(.+/)?">
    Require env localreferer
 </DirectoryMatch>
```

But all bin's subfolders are allowed from all referer.

What would be the correct regular expression to allow /bin/public to be accessed from any referer and /bin/private only from the ones I have on the list

Thanks in advance

Comment: i found the issue and the solution. i need to use LocationMatch instead of DirectoryMatch, so
SetEnvIf Referer "((.+\.)?domain\.com|localhost)" localreferer
<LocationMathc "/bin(.+/)?">
   Require env localreferer
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMathc "/bin/public(.+/)?">
   Require all granted
</LocationMatch>

Answer (score 1):

i found the issue and the solution. i need to use LocationMatch instead of DirectoryMatch, so

```
SetEnvIf Referer "((.+\.)?domain\.com|localhost)" localreferer 
<LocationMatch "/bin(.+/)?"> 
      Require env localreferer
 </LocationMatch> 

<LocationMatch "/bin/public(.+/)?"> 
      Require all granted 
</LocationMatch>
```